# Pushing/Pulling file in the artifactory

Tags: java, client, artifactory

I am trying to pushing and pulling file in jFrog artifactory. I have started it and running on port 8081. I have used following code but getting error.

```
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClient.create("http://localhost:8081/artifactory", "admin", "password");
InputStream content = new ByteArrayInputStream("I want to test my upload!".getBytes());

        UploadableArtifact apAtrifact =  artifactory.repository("libs-release-local").upload("resources/mock-data.xlsx", content);
        File deployed = (File) apAtrifact.doUpload();
```

I am getting following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad  method call from inside of a branch

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/jfrog/artifactory/client/impl/UploadableArtifactImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Lorg/jfrog/artifactory/client/Artifactory;)V @119: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 203a 0507 bd00 4559 032b 5359 042c
    0000010: 5359 0519 0512 4632 2db9 004c 0200 5359
    0000020: 0619 0453 5910 ff12 02b8 0050 2a5f ab00
    0000030: 0000 0084 0000 0002 ce18 5742 0000 001a
    0000040: 7059 1b58 0000 004f 5f5a 5903 32b8 0036
    0000050: c000 385f 5904 32b8 0036 c000 385f 5905
    0000060: 3212 3cb8 002e c000 3c5f 5906 3212 52b8
    0000070: 002e c000 525f 57b7 0054 a700 425f 5a59
    0000080: 0332 b800 36c0 0038 5f59 0432 b800 36c0
    0000090: 0038 5f59 0532 1256 b800 2ec0 0056 5f59
    00000a0: 0632 1252 b800 2ec0 0052 5f57 b700 58a7
    00000b0: 000d bb00 5a59 125c b700 5dbf 572d 3a06
    00000c0: 1906 1256 b800 2ec0 0056 2a5f b500 5f19
    00000d0: 0657 b1                                
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@72,{UninitializedThis,Object[#56],Object[#56],Object[#86],Object[#82],Object[#97]},{Object[#99],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@125,{UninitializedThis,Object[#56],Object[#56],Object[#86],Object[#82],Object[#97]},{Object[#99],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@178,{UninitializedThis,Object[#56],Object[#56],Object[#86],Object[#82],Object[#97]},{Object[#99],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@188,{Object[#2],Object[#56],Object[#56],Object[#86],Object[#82],Object[#97]},{Object[#99]})

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2$1.run(CachedClass.java:69)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors(CachedClass.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:189)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:193)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:158)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:148)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:241)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:859)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:202)
    at org.jfrog.artifactory.client.impl.RepositoryHandleImpl.upload(RepositoryHandleImpl.groovy:70)
```

EDIT For Search Artifacts:

```
List<RepoPath> repoPath = artifactoryClient.searches().itemsByProperty().property("version", "1.2").doSearch();
        System.out.println("Repo Size : "+repoPath.size());
        for (RepoPath path : repoPath) {
            System.out.println("Mine Path: "+path);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: @JigarJoshi Actually I need to use artifactory through Maven. Is there any java api?

Comment: You can attach any kind of files via [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to any existing artifact which means having at least a pom artifact. But bear in mind what Jigar Joshi mentioned.

Comment: @JigarJoshi what the hell are you talking about?! Since when Binary Repository was not designed to manage files?!

Comment: @kumar which Java version you are running the client on?

Comment: @JBaruch Java 1.7 version.

Comment: Can you give it a try with the latest updates or 1.7 and 1.8?

Comment: @JBaruch artifactory updates or what? I am running 3.4.2 artifactory version.

Comment: @JBaruch which updates you are taking about? Could You Please make it more clear. Am I doing right way to upload or download. Thanks.

Comment: Answered in the chat.

Comment: @JBaruch If I have RepoPath object; how can i get only downloadUri for the file from the object. I am able to get the reporPath object from serach using java client.?

Comment: Download URI is the Artifactory host + port + context name + repoName + repoPath.

Comment: @JBaruch is not possible only to get the downloadUri i.e. http://localhost:8081/.....only??

Comment: I just answered you how to do it :) String concatenation FTW.

Comment: @JBaruch Thanks..I got it. I have uploaded excel file with property "version"- 1.0,1.1 and so on. When I am searching it through search() with property; it is always returning value for latest version and previous version file is gone. Is it possible to get the download link after searching through property using java client. Please Check question update for the code.

Comment: @JBaruch Hi , I want to know how should I upload a file into respository version wise through simple java code? or how should i upload a file into reposirity through java code in maven artifact